# How to use targetStates in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, state, state-machine

I have several states, and I want to go from a particular state to 2 others states that are in parallelStates.

```
// This is what I use to go from a state to another
SignalTransition {
   targetState: state21
   signal: someSignal
}
```

And to go to 2 states in parallel

```
// This is what I want to use to go from a state to 2 others in parallel
SignalTransition {
   targetStates: [state21, state22]
   signal: someSignal
}
```

Unfortunately, i get the following error : Unable to assign QJSValue to [unknown property type]

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Does it even support having 2 active states at the same time?

Comment: Well according to qt docs, targetStates, as opposed to targetState, can : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-qabstracttransition.html

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that. Looks like the code should work.

Comment: There is a Section "Using Parallel States" here: doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html - I have never done anything like that, but I hope you might find the solution. I have the feeling  the problem resides within the sentence: "If multiple states are specified, they all must be descendants of the same parallel group state." from the link you shared.